# Android - using tesseract

Tags: android, ocr, tesseract

I'm using tess-two API and it works fine when I have a white paper with black words on it. My main problem is it gets some random text when the picture I captured doesn't contain any text. I've been searching around but didn't find anything useful. Is there any built-in methods to decide if it finds any text or I should use something else?

```
TessBaseAPI baseApi = new TessBaseAPI();
baseApi.init(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/tesseract", "eng");
baseApi.setImage(bitmap);
String recognizedText = baseApi.getUTF8Text();
baseApi.end();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the `HydrogenTextDetector` class in the eyes-two project.

You should already have the source code because you have tess-two, but there is [another build step you'll need to run to build the eyes-two project](https://github.com/rmtheis/tess-two#build).

Comment: Your answer is much appreciated, I'll take a look at it.